# why can they get the same result in python2.7? about assignment for each element in list

Tags: python, list

I create a list that like `aa=[ [] for i in range(10)]` and I want assignment for each element!

I use two method to do this,but one methon can work and another can't work, I can not know why.

PLease tell me! thanks!

```
aa=[ [] for i in range(10)]
```

method one: can't work as I want.

```
for a in aa:a=[2]   it get the result [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

method two: can work as I want.

```
for i in range(len(aa)): aa[i]=[2]
```

it get the result

```
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

I do another test that:

```
for index,a in enumerate(aa): print aa[index] is `a`
```

and the result is all true.

I think `a` and `aa[i]` are the same, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: This is not very clear. What do you mean with "assignment for each element"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here:

```
for a in aa:
  a = [2]
```

You're not assigning to the actual `aa` list, just to a local variable called `a` created for iterating over the list; the variable `a` previously was pointing to a position inside `aa` but now you assigned `[2]` to it, changing the value of the variable, but didn't modify `aa` at all. That's why it doesn't work. On the other hand, in here:

```
for i in range(len(aa)):
    aa[i] = [2]
```

You're *really* modifying a position inside `aa`, so the value `[2]` gets assigned at the `aa[i]` position.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I think I get the answers!

Answer (score 2):

The first loop assigns `a` to each of the elements of `aa` in turn, but the `=` reassigns `a` which doesn't affect `aa` at all.

The second loop modifies `aa` directly, which works as you'd expect.

To demonstrate the first effect, change your test a little bit:

```
for index,a in enumerate(aa):
    print aa[index] is a  # should print 'True'
    a = [2]
    print aa[index] is a  # should print 'False' because you've reassigned a
```

Comment: Thankes for you help,I do as you say and the result also the same with you, but why is it so?Is that the element which the first loop get can only be readed?